# Using first-child/nth-child/last-child in postcss lost-grid plugin

Tags: css, grid-layout, postcss

I am trying to use [Lost Grid](https://github.com/peterramsing/lost#controlling-cycle) with postCSS and trying to understand why the following code does not work;

HTML

```
 <section class="grid-two">
            <div class="grid-item-two"></div>
            <div class="grid-item-two"></div>
            <div class="grid-item-two"></div>
 </section>
```

CSS

```
.grid-two {
    lost-utility: clearfix;
    lost-move: 0.85/6;
    lost-column: 5.15/6;
    height: 100%;
}

.grid-item-two  {
    lost-column: 1.75/6;
    background: #2c3e50;
    height: 100px;
    &:first-child {
    }
    &:nth-child(1n){
            lost-column: 2.45/6;
    }
    &:last-child {
    }
}
```

I expect to see;

[image]

but this is the result;

[image]

I've also set up a code pen;

http://codepen.io/alexc101/pen/mEJQaR?editors=110

I'm just trying to understand what the code is doing here, and what is the proper way for me to achieve the desired effect seen in the first picture.

Hope it all makes sense,

Thanks